# Vim: use the path of the current file

Tags: vim

In Vim, how can I capture the path of the current file?

I know that the `%` register contains the name of the current file, but I want the path, so I can do something like

```
:w **bar.txt
```

... to "Save As" a new file, with ** representing the current file's path so that the new file will go in the same folder.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233905/howto-get-full-path-of-current-file-in-vim

`%` is the actual file

```
%:p:h
```

is the dirname of the file

```
%:p
```

is the full path of the file. Use what you prefer.

In order to save files, just

```
:w %:p:h/something
```